# How to get my dynamically created div to show up on page after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a project that I am trying to implement with jquery. I have an add button, so everytime it is clicked, it will create a new record on in my database. I am trying to figure out how to get my ajax call to recognize the new data and display it on the screen, without me having to manually refresh the screen, I was hoping to just use fadeIn or something similar to only show my new div.

This is for a checklist system,so someone can edit a checklist by adding steps on the fly and reorder existing steps
I wrote a loadData function to loop through my records and append the appropriate data, but not sure how to auto refresh my div when someone adds a new step. I don't want to reload the entire page, only the newly created div.

```js
$(function() {
  loadData();
});
// drag and drop steps and update the database
$('#steps').sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

    data = data + '&id=' + json.IDchecklist + '&ver=' + json.Version;
    $.ajax({
      data: data,
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../Processes/Reorder.php',
      success: (function() {})

    });

  }
});

//load data
function loadData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '../json/test.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      json = data
      $('#details').find('h2').html(data.IDchecklist);
      $('#details').find('h4').html(data.Status);
      $.each(data, function(k, v) {

        if (k == "Steps") {
          count = 1;
          $.each(v, function(key, value) {
            $('#steps').append('<span>' + count + '</span><div id=step' + value.IDstep + '>' + value.StepText + '</div>');
            count++;
            text[count] = value.StepText;
          })
        }
      })

    }
  })
}
//add new step
$('#add').click(function() {
  console.log(count);
  div = $('#step-' + count);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      id: json.IDchecklist,
      ver: json.Version,
      step: count
    },
    url: '../processes/addStep.php',
    success: (function() {

      div.fadeIn('fast')

    })
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron"></div>
<div id="details">
  <h2></h2>
  <h4></h4>
</div>
<div id="steps">

</div>
<button id=add value="Add">Add</button>
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined` something adds not up here. I guess it should be `var count = 1;`

Comment: Its been a while since I've done JQuery, but if I remember the good Ol' days correctly you could use your LoadData function and change it a bit to load only the last div added. Use this function in your success callback. Or call your LoadData function in your success callback (this might be a performance hit though)

Comment: Could it be that `<div id=step' + value.IDstep + '>'` should be `<div id=step-' + value.IDstep + '>'` the first one is missing a dash `id=step-`

Comment: I do have the dash in my code, I probably accidentally deleted it when copying the code to this board. Thanks